# Generic class for performing mass-parallel queries. Feedback?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I don't understand why, but there appears to be no mechanism in the client library for performing many queries in parallel for Windows Azure Table Storage. I've created a template class that can be used to save considerable time, and you're welcome to use it however you wish. I would appreciate however, if you could pick it apart, and provide feedback on how to improve this class.

```
public class AsyncDataQuery<T> where T: new()
{
    public AsyncDataQuery(bool preserve_order)
    {
        m_preserve_order = preserve_order;
        this.Queries = new List<CloudTableQuery<T>>(1000);
    }

    public void AddQuery(IQueryable<T> query)
    {
        var data_query = (DataServiceQuery<T>)query;
        var uri = data_query.RequestUri; // required

        this.Queries.Add(new CloudTableQuery<T>(data_query));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Blocking but still optimized.
    /// </summary>
    public List<T> Execute()
    {
        this.BeginAsync();
        return this.EndAsync();
    }

    public void BeginAsync()
    {
        if (m_preserve_order == true)
        {
            this.Items = new List<T>(Queries.Count);
            for (var i = 0; i < Queries.Count; i++)
            {
                this.Items.Add(new T());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.Items = new List<T>(Queries.Count * 2);
        }

        m_wait = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        for (var i = 0; i < Queries.Count; i++)
        {
            var query = Queries[i];
            query.BeginExecuteSegmented(callback, i);
        }
    }

    public List<T> EndAsync()
    {
        m_wait.WaitOne();
        m_wait.Dispose();

        return this.Items;
    }

    private List<T> Items { get; set; }
    private List<CloudTableQuery<T>> Queries { get; set; }

    private bool m_preserve_order;
    private ManualResetEvent m_wait;
    private int m_completed = 0;
    private object m_lock = new object();

    private void callback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        int i = (int)ar.AsyncState;
        CloudTableQuery<T> query = Queries[i];
        var response = query.EndExecuteSegmented(ar);
        if (m_preserve_order == true)
        { // preserve ordering only supports one result per query
            lock (m_lock)
            {
                this.Items[i] = response.Results.Single();
            }
        }
        else
        { // add any number of items
            lock (m_lock)
            {
                this.Items.AddRange(response.Results);
            }
        }
        if (response.HasMoreResults == true)
        { // more data to pull
            query.BeginExecuteSegmented(response.ContinuationToken, callback, i);
            return;
        }
        m_completed = Interlocked.Increment(ref m_completed);
        if (m_completed == Queries.Count)
        {
            m_wait.Set();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As a side note, this is running in production (on newscandy.com), and appears to work well for my usage, so far. But there seems to be much room for improvement.

Comment: From a quick look: Don't expose setters for collections, and don't expose concrete collection implementations.

Comment: Good advice. I agree implementation could use more consideration too. Anything as far as functional improvements? Be it for performance or function.

Comment: Does the callback get called in multiple threads? I doesn't look thread-safe to me. In particular the `Items.AddRange` call. And your code should throw an exception when it can't preserve the order because there are multiple results. You could use `.Single` instead of `.First`

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to handle cancelations and timeouts.  A source of inspiration is here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimoneil/archive/2010/10/05/azure-home-part-7-asynchronous-table-storage-pagination.aspx

Comment: This sounds like it should go on codereview.stackexchange.com instead of here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Guess I'm late to the party. I would add two things:

1. ManualResetEvent is IDisposable. So you need to make sure it gets disposed somewhere.
2. Error handling - if one of the queries fails it'll probably fail the whole thing. You should probably retry failed requests. Alternatively you could return the values you did get back with some indication of which queries failed, so that the caller could retry the queries.
3. Client side timeouts - there are none. This isn't a problem if the server side times out for you, but if that ever fails (eg, network issues) the client will hang forever.

Also, I think this is actually a better approach that the Task Parallel Library. I tried the Task-per-query approach before this. The code was actually more awkward, and it tended to result in having a *lot* of active threads. I still haven't tested extensively with your code, but it seems to work better on first blush.

### Update

I've put some work into a more-or-less rewrite of the code above. My rewrite removes all locking, supports client-side timeouts of hung transactions (rare, but it does happen, and can really ruin your day), and some exception handling logic. There is a full solution with tests up on [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/breischl/sepialabs.azure/src). The most relevant code lives in [one file](https://bitbucket.org/breischl/sepialabs.azure/src/0f92178ab98e/Sepialabs.Azure/ParallelTableQuery.cs), though it does require some helpers that are in other parts of the project.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, not sure how I missed it. Great feedback. 

I added the manual Dispose call on the ManualResetEvent, but ultimately it was getting destroyed upon call of destructor which is invoked by the GC. Manually invoking Dispose is really only a concern under (very) high volume.

Error handling is another good suggestion, but don't have the time to debug it right now (since I'm not using it). Feel free to contribute back, however, and I'll happily update the template!

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered using the Task Parallel Library?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx

Comment: Good suggestion. I'm not sure it would afford me much benefit at this point, but if I were starting from scratch I'd probably try out that route. I would recommend Task Parallel Library for those not real comfortable with multi-threaded development for sure.