# Query execution using AND on Azure table is very slow

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

If I try this:

```
( RowKey ge '1606780800000' )
```

I get results back in one second.

But if I try with `AND`, still using RowKey like this:

```
( RowKey ge '1606780800000' and RowKey le '1606784400000' )
```

It keeps loading forever.

I know that [with `OR` it will perform a full scan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11973560/679318), but is the same case with `AND`? Any way to go around this?

Comment: how many of the results that should be returned? Regarding "It keeps loading forever.", you mean no results returned?

Comment: @IvanYang I mean it keeps waiting for the results to come, but since there is too much data to scan, it stays there "forever". After half hour I just give up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If just using `2 RowKeys with AND` operator(without PartitionKey),it will do table scan.

Here are some suggestions:

1.You can use [range query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-design-guide#how-your-choice-of-partitionkey-and-rowkey-affects-query-performance) if possible. Then you can specify the filter like `$filter=PartitionKey eq 'xxx' and RowKey ge '1606780800000' and RowKey le '1606784400000'`. But you need to write more than one queries if there're one more than PartitionKeys.

2.If you still use this query: `( RowKey ge '1606780800000' and RowKey le '1606784400000' )` . At this time, if the `requested items` are more than 1000, the query can only return a maximum of 1000 items at one time. So in this case, you should use `x-ms-continuation-NextPartitionKey` and `x-ms-continuation-NextRowKey` in your query. See [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/query-timeout-and-pagination) for more details.

Comment: I am going to accept this as answer because it answers my question whether it performs a table scan or not. Now I know, and this explains why it takes so long. Also, your suggestions may help others. In my particular case does not help because it wouldn't be practical. I would have to run the query around 12000 times to cover all possible PartitionKey. Since the period I wanted to query is recent, I just fetched all rows since a certain day, and then I programmatically discarded the rows I didn't want.